# Cannot solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide the `accountSlider` div on the press of a button. However, When I press the button I get: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null*

How could I fix this?

Here is my Code

```
<style>

    .hideSlider {
        transform: translateX(-110%);
    }
</style>
<script>

    const accountSlider = document.getElementById("accountSlider");
    const imageX = document.getElementById("imageX");

    function hideSlider() {
        accountSlider.classList.add("hideSlider");
    }

</script>

<div class="accountSlider">
    <button id="closeButton" onclick="hideSlider()">
        <img src="@/assets/closeX.png" width="30" class="buttonImg" id="imageX" />
    </button>
</div>
```

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Your script is located prior to your HTML elements and so it is executing before the HTML has been parsed into memory. Move the script to just before the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's pretty simple: if you define the DOM nodes you are trying to retrieve synchronously in the script that is executed **before** these DOM nodes are even created, the methods will return undefined, as nothing is live yet.

If you move your selectors within the global function you are defining (a bad practice, yet allowed), you won't have issues.

```
function hideSlider() {
    const accountSlider = document.querySelector(".accountSlider");
    accountSlider.classList.add("hideSlider");
}
```

That's it.

Comment: *the methods will return undefined* No, they return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your html attribute  is class not id. Changes it ti this

```
<div id="accountSlider">
    <button id="closeButton" onclick="hideSlider()">
        <img src="@/assets/closeX.png" width="30" class="buttonImg" id="imageX" />
    </button>
</div>
```

or use querySelector(".accountSlider")

Comment: [Don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Use `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Can you give us a sandbox or your entry html

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` method take ID name as argument not class name.

```js
const accountSlider = document.getElementsByClassName("accountSlider")[0];/*or use document.querySelector(".accountSlider");*/
    const imageX = document.getElementById("imageX");

    function hideSlider() {
        accountSlider.classList.add("hideSlider");
    }
```

```css
    .hideSlider {
        transform: translateX(-110%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="accountSlider">
    <button id="closeButton" onclick="hideSlider()">
        <img src="@/assets/closeX.png" alt = 'a unknown image' width="30" class="buttonImg" id="imageX" />
    </button>
</div>
```